# How to detect, when loadComplete event fire, that the event is performed after a search?

Tags: events, search, jqgrid

How to detect, when loadComplete event fire, that the event is performed after a search ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you need this, but you can test whether `search` parameter of jqGrid is true. Inside of `loadComplete` function if can be like `if(this.p.search) {/*do something*/}`.